# How to make a query not referring to the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate amount of spaces in string by this query

```
SELECT LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM('Im i student of the Academy')))-LEN(REPLACE('Im i student of the Academy',' ',''))  as Spacecount
```

But i get "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"
Probably this question seems stupid but i really dont know how to deal with it

Comment: Try to add  "from dual" at the end

Comment: Somewhat simpler code than yours: `select regexp_count('Im i student of the Academy', ' ') result from dual;`